tab bar is not changing flutter
I have demo code for bottom bar below but when I tap on second tab, related screen is not changing.
It is very basic example and should change tabs, may be it is silly mistake as I am just beginner in flutter.
I am using GetX for routing via GetMaterialApp.
so InitialRoute is tab screen.
class TabScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabScreen> createState() => _TabScreenState();
}

class _TabScreenState extends State<TabScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int currentIndex = 0;
    final List<Widget> screens = [const Text('A'), const Text('B')];

    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


It should show second tab screen.

Please declare the currentIndex outside of the build method because after the setState build method is triggered again, the currentIndex will be 0. For this reason, your pages have not changed.

The problem you are facing is because your variable
int currentIndex = 0;

is inside build methode. When you click on 2nd button while currentIndex is inside of build methode it will not change state.
And if currentIndex is out side of build methode and you click on 2nd button it change from outside of build methode and then it change to second screen.
So keep variables out side of build methode. Only place those variables inside build methode which need to initialz at once.

int currentIndex = 0; should defined in _TabScreenState instead of build method.
class _TabScreenState extends State<TabScreen> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> screens = [const Text('A'), const Text('B')];

    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


The issue in your code is that the currentIndex variable is inside the build method, which causes it to reset to 0 every time the widget rebuilds. To fix this, move the currentIndex variable outside of the build method so it persists across widget rebuilds.
Here’s the corrected code
 class TabScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabScreen> createState() => _TabScreenState();
}

class _TabScreenState extends State<TabScreen> {
  int currentIndex = 0; // Move the currentIndex here

  final List<Widget> screens = [const Text('A'), const Text('B')];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex], // Display the selected screen
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index; // Update the currentIndex on tap
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class _TabScreenState extends State<TabScreen> {
  /// current selected index
  int currentIndex = 0;
  /// list of tabs
  final List<Widget> screens = [const Text('A'), const Text('B')];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

